# Eclipse can't start after update

Tags: eclipse

After the eclipse update, it can't start up again. Also, it has a warning to check the log.
But I don't know how to fix this problem through the log.
Following is the log.

```
!SESSION 2012-10-15 08:21:47.367 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
java.version=1.7.0_01
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.event 2 0 2012-10-15 08:21:48.459
!MESSAGE [SCR] Found components with duplicated names! Details: 
Component1 : Component[
    name = org.eclipse.equinox.event
    activate = activate
    deactivate = deactivate
    modified = 
    configuration-policy = optional
    factory = null
    autoenable = true
    immediate = false
    implementation = org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent
    state = Unsatisfied
    properties = 
    serviceFactory = false
    serviceInterface = [org.osgi.service.event.EventAdmin]
    references = null
    located in bundle = org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.2.100.v20110502 [270]
]
Component2: Component[
    name = org.eclipse.equinox.event
    activate = activate
    deactivate = deactivate
    modified = 
    configuration-policy = optional
    factory = null
    autoenable = true
    immediate = false
    implementation = org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent
    state = Unsatisfied
    properties = 
    serviceFactory = false
    serviceInterface = [org.osgi.service.event.EventAdmin]
    references = null
    located in bundle = org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.2.200.v20120522-2049 [89]
]  

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 2 0 2012-10-15 08:21:48.474
!MESSAGE [SCR] Found components with duplicated names! Details: 
Component1 : Component[
    name = org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf
    activate = activate
    deactivate = deactivate
    modified = 
    configuration-policy = optional
    factory = null
    autoenable = true
    immediate = false
    implementation = org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.ECFTransportComponent
    state = Unsatisfied
    properties = {p2.agent.servicename=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.Transport}
    serviceFactory = false
    serviceInterface = [org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.spi.IAgentServiceFactory]
    references = null
    located in bundle = org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf_1.0.0.v20111128-0624 [275]
]
Component2: Component[
    name = org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf
    activate = activate
    deactivate = deactivate
    modified = 
    configuration-policy = optional
    factory = null
    autoenable = true
    immediate = false
    implementation = org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.ECFTransportComponent
    state = Unsatisfied
    properties = {p2.agent.servicename=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.Transport}
    serviceFactory = false
    serviceInterface = [org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.spi.IAgentServiceFactory]
    references = null
    located in bundle = org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf_1.0.100.v20120305-0333 [120]
]  

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2012-10-15 08:21:49.535
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2012-10-15 08:21:52.000
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.CommandServiceAddon' from bundle '53'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.eclipse.core.commands.CommandManager to org.eclipse.core.commands.CommandManager
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:859)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.eclipse.core.commands.CommandManager to org.eclipse.core.commands.CommandManager
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.get(EclipseContext.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.CommandServiceAddon.init(CommandServiceAddon.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    ... 27 more
```

Basically, it just a part in the log file. From here, I found some post and tried:

1) eclipse -clean
2) delete .snap
3) delete workbench.xmi
4) rename org.eclipse.core.resources
etc..

Unfortunately, they are not work.

Comment: Finally, I removed the previous eclipse and install the eclipse again. The problem be fixed.

Answer (score 39):

go to

1. Your installation path\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\
2. Backup file bundle.info
3. remove the duplicate entry for "org.eclipse.core.commands" from the file `bundle.info`
   I removed the entry with the lower version.

restart the eclipse with option `-clean` and you should be fine

Answer (score 2):

i have the same problem, after i updated my pydev.

i re-extract JUNO to my installation dir

problem solved

Comment: No, that didn't do it for me either.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Go into damaged workspace/.metadata and delete the .lock file.
Go to workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources and delete the .snap file.
Start Eclipse with the command eclipse -clean.
Eclipse should start now. After Eclipse has been started and has initialized and validated the workspace, close Eclipse.

Comment: No, that does not work for me.  I deleted the .lock file, however I have no .snap file.  Starting eclipse with -clean does nothing.

Comment: @IgorG. Is the path really correct? Had this issue in Inigo and Juno and it worked both.

Comment: Hi, .snap would only be in one directory on my own machine: ~/tests/.metadata/
I couldn't find .snap anywhere.

Comment: @IgorG. This is a really strange since .snap represents the changes in workspace so it's unclear to me why this file is not within your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Name" of your ComponentDefinitions in the Overview Tab(*.xml)
If there are two ComponentDefinitions with different File names but the same "Name"-value in the Overview Tab, then this error occurs.