# Eclipse Juno can't start after update

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

I've seen other questions like [Eclipse juno can't start after update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320583/eclipse-juno-cant-start-up-after-update). My problem is similar to that one but the error log is little different. As seen in another question, I've deleted `.lock` file, no `.snap` file and started `eclipse -clean`, but still the problem persists. I've executed `eclipse` from terminal but no messages is displayed and following message is shown.

[image: Eclipse error in startup]

The beginning of log file is as follows.

```
!SESSION 2013-03-14 10:45:43.362 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_15
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 4 0 2013-03-14 10:45:44.307
!MESSAGE [SCR] Exception while activating instance org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngineManager@28fed5b1 of component org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme  
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1810)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.getMethod(ServiceComponent.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 15 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.ds 4 0 2013-03-14 10:45:44.309
!MESSAGE [SCR] Exception while activating instance org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.internal.theme.ThemeEngineManager@28fed5b1 of component org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.theme  
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2451)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1810)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.getMethod(ServiceComponent.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 15 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-03-14 10:45:44.833
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench (499).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin for bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench is invalid
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 43 more
Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/SWTError
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadBundleActivator(AbstractBundle.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.setLazyTrigger(BundleLoader.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2413)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2723)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:345)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 43 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.608
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.608
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.pde.ui_3.7.2.v20130121-093123.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.ui 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.608
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.mylyn.java.tasks_3.8.2.v20120916-1200.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.mylyn.java.tasks 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.608
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ant.ui_3.5.301.v20121210-210948.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ant.ui 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.608
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui_[3.6.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.routineeditor.ui_1.0.3.v201211200616.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.routineeditor.ui 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml_1.3.1.20130219-1424.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.ui_3.1.0.201210040458-RELEASE.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.ui 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.debugger.core.ui_1.0.0.v201003161000.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.debugger.core.ui 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.externaltools_3.2.100.v20120530-1753.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.externaltools 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.ui_3.8.2.v20130107-165834.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.launching_1.3.1.20130219-1424.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.m2e.launching 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.m2e.launching 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.refactoring_1.3.1.20130219-1424.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.m2e.refactoring 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.junit_3.7.100.v20120523-1543.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.junit 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui_3.6.100.v20120530-1425.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui_[3.8.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui_1.3.102.v201301162301.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.debug.ui_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ui_3.1.0.201210040510-RELEASE.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.springframework.ide.eclipse.ui 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.609
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.debug.ui_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-03-14 10:45:46.610
```

and the full log can be found in [gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/TheKojuEffect/5158958#file-eclipse-juno-startup-error).

How can I fix this problem?
I've plugins installed which I'd like to keep and don't wanna do all the re-installation.

Thanks.

Comment: Now, I merged a newly extracted eclipse/ folder with the existing installed eclipse folder. Now, eclipse/ run but my plugins are all gone. I hadn't deleted previous eclipse/ folder but merged it so the plugins should be available, isn't it? How can I get my plugins back? HELP!!!

Comment: The merge of the new copy likely overwrote your p2 profile settings that erased the configuration for eclipse runtime that tells it what plugins to start.  You can try to File > Import > Plugins from install.." and point to your existing install and see if you can see your old plugins.

Comment: I did as you said. I can see my previously installed plugins but can't select any of them to install it. Running eclipse as normal user didn't let me go beyond import->install->From Existing Installation whereas running eclipse as root user didn't let me select as mentioned earlier.