# Unable to start Eclipse (Kepler)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Here is just a portion of the errors I'm getting from the event logs in Eclipse. It just wouldn't start earlier today and I've tried multiple solutions to try and fix the problem including redownloading the ADT Bundle from developer.android.com. Any ideas or suggestions?

```
!SESSION 2014-03-12 15:00:24.022 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.event 2 0 2014-03-12 15:00:26.773
!MESSAGE [SCR] Found components with duplicated names! Details: 
Component1 : Component[
name = org.eclipse.equinox.event
activate = activate
deactivate = deactivate
modified = 
configuration-policy = optional
factory = null
autoenable = true
immediate = false
implementation = org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent
state = Unsatisfied
properties = 
serviceFactory = false
serviceInterface = [org.osgi.service.event.EventAdmin]
references = null
located in bundle = org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.3.0.v20130327-1442 [191]
]
Component2: Component[
name = org.eclipse.equinox.event
activate = activate
deactivate = deactivate
modified = 
configuration-policy = optional
factory = null
autoenable = true
immediate = false
implementation = org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent
state = Unsatisfied
properties = 
serviceFactory = false
serviceInterface = [org.osgi.service.event.EventAdmin]
references = null
located in bundle = org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.2.200.v20120522-2049 [190]
]  

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.di 2 0 2014-03-12 15:00:26.819
!MESSAGE [SCR] Found components with duplicated names! Details: 
Component1 : Component[
name = org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.events
activate = activate
deactivate = deactivate
modified = 
configuration-policy = optional
factory = null
autoenable = true
immediate = false
implementation = org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.di.UIEventObjectSupplier
state = Unsatisfied
properties = {dependency.injection.annotation=org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.UIEventTopic}
serviceFactory = false
serviceInterface = [org.eclipse.e4.core.di.suppliers.ExtendedObjectSupplier]
references = null
located in bundle = org.eclipse.e4.ui.di_1.0.0.v20130515-1857 [136]
]
Component2: Component[
name = org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.events
activate = activate
deactivate = deactivate
modified = 
configuration-policy = optional
factory = null
autoenable = true
immediate = false
implementation = org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.di.UIEventObjectSupplier
state = Unsatisfied
properties = {dependency.injection.annotation=org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.UIEventTopic}
serviceFactory = false
serviceInterface = [org.eclipse.e4.core.di.suppliers.ExtendedObjectSupplier]
references = null
located in bundle = org.eclipse.e4.ui.di_0.10.1.v20120523-1955 [135]
]  

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 2 0 2014-03-12 15:00:26.866
!MESSAGE [SCR] Found components with duplicated names! Details: 
Component1 : Component[
name = org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf
activate = activate
deactivate = deactivate
modified = 
configuration-policy = optional
factory = null
autoenable = true
immediate = false
implementation = org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.ECFTransportComponent
state = Unsatisfied
properties = {p2.agent.servicename=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.Transport}
serviceFactory = false
serviceInterface = [org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.spi.IAgentServiceFactory]
references = null
located in bundle = org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf_1.1.0.v20130516-1858 [231]
]
Component2: Component[
name = org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf
activate = activate
deactivate = deactivate
modified = 
configuration-policy = optional
factory = null
autoenable = true
immediate = false
implementation = org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.ECFTransportComponent
state = Unsatisfied
properties = {p2.agent.servicename=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.Transport}
serviceFactory = false
serviceInterface = [org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.spi.IAgentServiceFactory]
references = null
located in bundle = org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf_1.0.100.v20120913-155635 [230]
]
```

**EDIT:** This is another error log. This **is not** the full error log. It's actually crazy long, but this should help give a better idea of my issue. I would prefer not to completely nuke the install, but if I need to that is fine.

```
!SESSION 2014-03-12 16:10:28.052 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=v22.3.0-887826
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product -clean

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk_1.0.200.v20120515-1650.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.3.v20120522.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.http_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.io_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.continuation_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.security_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.100.v20130327-1442.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.http_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.io.bio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.14.v20131031.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.security_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.io_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.http_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.continuation_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.server 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.continuation_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.server 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.http_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.server 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.io_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.server 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.server 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.io.bio_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.server 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.http.gzip_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.apache.sshd.core_0.7.0.v201303101611.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.sshd.core 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.mina.core.filterchain_[2.0.0,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.sshd.core 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.mina.util_[2.0.0,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.sshd.core 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio_[2.0.0,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.sshd.core 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.mina.core.service_[2.0.0,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.sshd.core 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.mina.core.future_[2.0.0,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.sshd.core 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.mina.filter.executor_[2.0.0,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.sshd.core 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.slf4j_[1.6.0,2.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.sshd.core 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.mina.transport.socket_[2.0.0,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.sshd.core 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.mina.core.session_[2.0.0,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.sshd.core 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.mina.core.buffer_[2.0.0,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.releng.tools_3.6.100.v20120531-1322/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.releng.tools 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.cvs.ui_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.releng.tools 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.cvs.core_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler_1.1.0.v20110815-1744.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler 2 0 2014-03-12 16:11:06.458
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1)))".
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer? What else have you tried?

Comment: That did not work. It generated another error log with similar errors.

Comment: a similar question in [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888156/eclipse-cant-start-after-update)

Comment: Is your kepler a clean install?

Comment: might suggest pulling down another version and starting eclipse from there, and connect to your existing workspace

Comment: Do you mean copying the entire ADT bundle from the website? I've tried that already.

Comment: Have you already tried an `eclipse -clean`?

Comment: I have done so multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your installation path_to_eclipse_installation\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\
2. Backup file bundle.info as `cp bundle.info bundle.info.bak`
3. Remove the duplicate entry for "org.eclipse.equinox.event" from the file bundle.info
4. Restart your eclipse with -clean option

Comment: I just observed you have more duplicate names. Did you try removing other duplicates? org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.events, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf

Comment: Tried that, still had issues.