# Installing some plugins caused eclipse/RAD to stop working - How do I uninstall or go back to previous version?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, restart, rad

I installed some Hibernate Tools plug-ins and my eclipse/RAD is not starting now.

Here are the exceptions from the [log file](http://tny.cz/1cfc0988).
Anyone has any idea? I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14516016/668650). But no use.

If at all its not possible, I would like to go back to previous point, if any like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6469192/668650)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding as an answer.

I presume you used p2 to install Hibernate (Help > Install new software or Eclipse Marketplace). P2 has a command-line utility to run headless installation processes. In this blog post, I depict how to install RTC on top of RAD https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/victorsh/entry/installing_rtc_client_402_on_rad_v90_in_command_line?lang=en What you need to do? Find out the feature group for Hibernate and use the uninstallIU argument http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_director.html

Answer (score 0):

The Uninstall thread in SO is correct. You can uninstall your Hibernate plugins by going Help -> About IBM Rational Application Developer -> Installation details. On the "Installed software" tab click on the software that you wish to uninstall, then click the "Uninstall..." button.

Comment: Well, I can't open the RAD to do that.

Comment: Right!
I presume you used p2 to install Hibernate (Help > Install new software or Eclipse Marketplace). P2 has a command-line utility to run headless installation processes. In this blog post, I depict how to install RTC on top of RAD
[https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/victorsh/entry/installing_rtc_client_402_on_rad_v90_in_command_line?lang=en]

What you need to do? Find out the feature group for Hibernate and use the uninstallIU argument
[http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_director.html]

Comment: Please add this to answer. I will accept it. This will be helpful to others.