# Eclipse just doesn't start

Tags: java, eclipse

I know others have asked this question but I've tried all the suggestions and none have even made the slightest difference. So was I have my console log for people to see in case I've missed a problem.
When I click on the Eclipse.exe nothing happens, no error message, no splash screen, it doesn't show up in task manager, nothing.
I've taken screen shots of the consolelog,
[image: First screenshot of the consoleLog]

Comment: It looks like your Eclipse installation is messed up. Did you install a plug-in which is incompatible with your version of Eclipse?

Comment: The only time I had problems starting up, it was fixed by passing the clean option to the .exe .. Not sure if you tried this.

Comment: @vikingsteve that doesn't help to solve this problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza it's a workaround... works for me, for 7 years now ;)

Comment: @vikingsteve good to know, but still doesn't solve the problem :)

Comment: The error message you should search in your SEO is *eclipse found components with duplicated names*. Ive found this Q/A on this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12888156/1065197

Comment: This is a brand new download

Comment: Can you go into your workspace .metadata and check .log file. You might get some clue why your eclipse crashed. If incase it didn't even reach workspace, then check in your eclipse installed location for the log file. You will surely get a clue what's wrong during start up.